# How to create custom list accumulator, i.e. List[(Int, Int)]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, accumulator

I am trying to use custom accumulator in Apache Spark to accumulate pairs in a list.
The result should have `List[(Int, Int)]` type. For this I creat custom accumulator:

```
import org.apache.spark.AccumulatorParam

class AccumPairs extends AccumulatorParam[List[(Int,Int)]] {

    def zero(initialValue: List[(Int,Int)]): List[(Int,Int)] = {
      List()
    }

    def addInPlace(l1: List[(Int,Int)], l2: List[(Int,Int)]): List[(Int,Int)] = {
      l1 ++ l2
    }

 }
```

Yet I can not instantiate variable of this type.

```
val pairAccum = sc.accumulator(new List():List[(Int,Int)])(AccumPairs)
```

results in error. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This one works:

```
val pairAccum = sc.accumulator(List[(Int,Int)]())( new AccumPairs)
```

Answer (score 1):

A class without parameters doesn't make much sense (if at all) as you "implicitly" create a single value anyway<sup>1</sup>. Change the keyword `class` to `object` and your example will work.

Change

```
class AccumPairs extends AccumulatorParam[List[(Int,Int)]] {
```

to

```
object AccumPairs extends AccumulatorParam[List[(Int,Int)]] {
```

[1] You still could create multiple instances of the class but they effectively be alike.