# Serialising temp collections created in Spark executors during task execution

Tags: scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I'm trying to find an effective way of writing collections created inside tasks to the output files of the job. For example, if we iterate over a RDD using `foreach`, we can create data structures that are local to the executor ex.,`ListBuffer arr` in the following code snippet. My problem is that how do I serialise `arr` and write it to file? 
(1) Should I use `FileWriter` api or Spark `saveAsTextFile` will work? 
(2) What will be the advantages of using one over the other
(3) Is there a better way of achieving the same.

PS: The reason I am using `foreach` instead of `map` is because I might not be able to transform all my RDD rows and I want to avoid getting Null values in the output.

```
val dataSorted: RDD[(Int, Int)] = <Some Operation>
val arr: ListBuffer = ListBuffer[(String, String)]()
dataSorted.foreach {
     case (e, r) => {
     if(e.id > 1000) {
       arr += (("a", "b"))
     }
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Devj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use driver's variables, but Accumulators - therw are articles about them with code examples [here](https://www.brosinski.com/post/extending-spark-accumulators/) and [here](http://bigdatafindings.blogspot.com/2015/08/learning-spark-notes-advanced-spark.html), also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798578/how-to-create-custom-list-accumulator-i-e-listint-int/34798770) question maybe helpful - there is simplified code example of custom `AccumulatorParam`

Write your own accumulator, that is able to add `(String, String)` or use built-in [`CollectionAccumulator`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/util/CollectionAccumulator.html). This is implementation of AccumulatorV2, new version of accumulator from Spark 2

Other way is to use Spark built-in filter and map functions - thanks @ImDarrenG for suggesting flatMap, but I think filter and map will be easier:

```
val result : Array[(String, String)] = someRDD
    .filter(x => x._1 > 1000) // filter only good rows
    .map (x => ("a", "b"))
    .collect() // convert to arrat
```

Comment: Yeah that is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

The Spark API saves you some file handling code but essentially achieves the same thing.

The exception is if you are not using, say, HDFS and do not want your output file to be partitioned (spread across the executors file systems).  In this case you will need to collect the data to the driver and use FileWriter to write to a single file, or files, and how you achieve that will depend on how much data you have.  If you have more data than driver has memory you will need to handle it differently.

As mentioned in another answer, you're creating an array in your driver, while adding items from your executors, which will not work in a cluster environment. Something like this might be a better way to map your data and handle nulls:

```
val outputRDD = dataSorted.flatMap {
    case (e, r) => {
        if(e.id > 1000) {
            Some(("a", "b"))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
 }
 // save outputRDD to file/s here using the approapriate method...
```